# Parsear objetos JSON con nombres aleatorios

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Estoy intentando parsear objectos **JSON** con **GSON** estoy acostumbrado a que conozco los nombres de los objectos, creo las clases y solo tengo que llamar a esas clases para usar los objetos y construir los adaptadores personalizados y por ultimo llenar listas u otras vistas de forma fácil con GSON.

En este ejemplo no conozco los nombres de los objetos **JSON** ya que son bastante aleatorios y no es practico crear clases con esos nombres ademas que no existe unacantidad determinada de objetos es decir puede ser solo 1 o más de 10 por ejemplo, ¿existe alguna forma en la que pueda crear una clase java que contenga la información de las objetos y pueda crear listas u otras vistas usando o llamando a esa clase sin conocer los nombres?,

He leido en **Stackoverflow** algo referente a HashMap o Map así como también Gson deserealizer personalizado pero no estoy familiarizado con ello, ¿es posible usar GSON o debo implementar alguna otra lógica?, Gracias de antemano, les dejo el ejemplo del JSON, la cuestión esta en el objeto "items" como pueden notar no se conoce la cantidad y tampoco el del objeto nombre ya que son aleatorios, esto es para Android:

```
[
{
    "id": 1001,
    "name": "Super1",
    "user": {
        "character": "The Super 1"
    },
    "items": {
        "987987M7812b123": {
            "id": 1,
            "strong": 456,
            "active": true,
            "set": "tier1"
        },
        "90812bn120893": {
            "id": 2,
            "strong": 4700,
            "active": true,
            "set": "vex"
        },
        "981273jn19203nj": {
            "id": 3,
            "strong": 3000,
            "active": true,
            "set": "nesp"
        }
    }
}
]
```

Añado el código de la clase donde implemento GSON:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class test_de {

private int id;
private String name;
private UserBean user;
private ItemsBean items;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public UserBean getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(UserBean user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public ItemsBean getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setItems(ItemsBean items) {
    this.items = items;
}

public static class UserBean {
    /**
     * character : The Super 1
     */

    private String character;

    public String getCharacter() {
        return character;
    }

    public void setCharacter(String character) {
        this.character = character;
    }
}

public static class ItemsBean {
    /**
     * 987987M7812b123 : {"id":1,"strong":456,"active":true,"set":"tier1"}
     * 90812bn120893 : {"id":2,"strong":4700,"active":true,"set":"vex"}
     * 981273jn19203nj : {"id":3,"strong":3000,"active":true,"set":"nesp"}
     */

    @SerializedName("987987M7812b123")
    private _$987987M7812b123Bean _$987987M7812b123;
    @SerializedName("90812bn120893")
    private _$90812bn120893Bean _$90812bn120893;
    @SerializedName("981273jn19203nj")
    private _$981273jn19203njBean _$981273jn19203nj;

    public _$987987M7812b123Bean get_$987987M7812b123() {
        return _$987987M7812b123;
    }

    public void set_$987987M7812b123(_$987987M7812b123Bean _$987987M7812b123) {
        this._$987987M7812b123 = _$987987M7812b123;
    }

    public _$90812bn120893Bean get_$90812bn120893() {
        return _$90812bn120893;
    }

    public void set_$90812bn120893(_$90812bn120893Bean _$90812bn120893) {
        this._$90812bn120893 = _$90812bn120893;
    }

    public _$981273jn19203njBean get_$981273jn19203nj() {
        return _$981273jn19203nj;
    }

    public void set_$981273jn19203nj(_$981273jn19203njBean _$981273jn19203nj) {
        this._$981273jn19203nj = _$981273jn19203nj;
    }

    public static class _$987987M7812b123Bean {
        /**
         * id : 1
         * strong : 456
         * active : true
         * set : tier1
         */

        private int id;
        private int strong;
        private boolean active;
        private String set;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getStrong() {
            return strong;
        }

        public void setStrong(int strong) {
            this.strong = strong;
        }

        public boolean isActive() {
            return active;
        }

        public void setActive(boolean active) {
            this.active = active;
        }

        public String getSet() {
            return set;
        }

        public void setSet(String set) {
            this.set = set;
        }
    }

    public static class _$90812bn120893Bean {
        /**
         * id : 2
         * strong : 4700
         * active : true
         * set : vex
         */

        private int id;
        private int strong;
        private boolean active;
        private String set;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getStrong() {
            return strong;
        }

        public void setStrong(int strong) {
            this.strong = strong;
        }

        public boolean isActive() {
            return active;
        }

        public void setActive(boolean active) {
            this.active = active;
        }

        public String getSet() {
            return set;
        }

        public void setSet(String set) {
            this.set = set;
        }
    }

    public static class _$981273jn19203njBean {
        /**
         * id : 3
         * strong : 3000
         * active : true
         * set : nesp
         */

        private int id;
        private int strong;
        private boolean active;
        private String set;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getStrong() {
            return strong;
        }

        public void setStrong(int strong) {
            this.strong = strong;
        }

        public boolean isActive() {
            return active;
        }

        public void setActive(boolean active) {
            this.active = active;
        }

        public String getSet() {
            return set;
        }

        public void setSet(String set) {
            this.set = set;
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Generalmente GSON es para mapear tu JSON a una clase, lo cual significa que por lo general el JSON contiene los valores representados en la Clase. No creo que te convenga en este caso GSON. Quizá sea mejor otra clase en la que tengas un array con una especie de *lista blanca* donde tengas los posibles valores que podrían venir en el JSON y si los encuentra entonces obtener esos valores.

Comment: Como estas intentandolo, agrega ese código a tu pregunta. Es posible usar Gson y no son "nombres aleatorios", en realidad tiene una estructura definida.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente

- Lo que yo veo es que si tienes una estructura definida, ya que tiense user, items, etc.
- Creo que a lo que te refieres es que en el caso de los items, no sabes qué nombre puedan tener, por ejemplo `987987M7812b123` y no quieres crear una clase por cada uno. Si ese es el caso, puedes intentar lo siguiente:

Crea un objeto que soporte todos los atributos de tus items(id, strong, active), por ejemplo, asumamos que la clase se llama **atributos**:

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class atributos {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("strong")
@Expose
private Integer strong;
@SerializedName("active")
@Expose
private Boolean active;
@SerializedName("set")
@Expose
private String set;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public Integer getStrong() {
return strong;
}

public void setStrong(Integer strong) {
this.strong = strong;
}

public Boolean getActive() {
return active;
}

public void setActive(Boolean active) {
this.active = active;
}

public String getSet() {
return set;
}

public void setSet(String set) {
this.set = set;
}

}
```

Luego puedes parsearlo de la siguiente forma:

```
@SerializedName("items")
@Expose
private HashMap<String, atributos> items;
```

Espero que te ayude amigo :)

Comment: Excelente Brayan!!!, seria buena idea un ejemplo de como instanciar Gson. Para que se usaría en este caso la notación @Expose ?

Comment: Gracias Jorge, en este caso Expose no está sirviendo para nada, pero en caso de que quieras excluir campos que no tengan la notación te podría llegar a servir o si quieres indicar si se van a serializar y deserializar, en este caso lo puse, porque así me genero lo generó http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/, saludos @Jorgesys

Comment: Gracias @BrayanArmandoYaquianGonzale , como puedo llamar: private HashMap<String, atributos> items; desde un adaptador personalizado para organizar los items en una lista?